# When installing AMD drivers on Linux Mint, I get this error “unable to load driver: i965_dri.so"

Tags: linux, python, linux-mint, amd-radeon, pycharm

When installing **AMD drivers** on *Linux Mint*, I get this error:-

`libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
 libGL error: driver pointer missing
 libGL error: failed to load driver: i965`
and when I tried to run my program in **pycharm**, which is using *image operations*. I get the top errors + this error:-

```
Could not initialize GLX
```

Comment: What symptom initiated your action to manually install AMD drivers?  What is your hardware?

Comment: @fixer1234 I fixed it, but there's another problem. When I restarted the laptop I got an error message that `Cinnamon just crashed. You are currently running in Fallback Mode`.